# Swift tried to present modally an active controller [Current view controller] even though the presented controller is another one

Tags: ios, swift

I have read some answers like dismissing the current ViewController but my situation is different because I am presenting another ViewController.

This code presents the view controller with its navigation controller although I cannot access it's properties:

```
@IBAction func didTouchAddFriend(_ sender: UIButton) {
DispatchQueue.main.async {

    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "CustomContact", bundle: nil)
        let customContactVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CustomContact")

}
}
```

While this one doesn't work

```
@IBAction func didTouchAddFriend(_ sender: UIButton) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        let navigation = UIStoryboard.init(name: "CustomContact", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController() as! UINavigationController
        let pickerUserVC = navigation.viewControllers.first as! CustomContactsViewController
        self.present(pickerUserVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

I have another story board named CustomContact.storyboard which containts a CustomContactsViewController

When I click the didTouchAddFriend, it just shows me this error:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller <Main.MainViewController: 0x7ff29f06ac00>.'
```

I cannot understand the error cos when I printed the value of pickerUserVC, it show the right view controller:

```
<Main.CustomContactsViewController: 0x7fd1b7922400>
```

MainViewController is the current view controller implementing the didTouchAddFriend function

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You ought to present the *navigation controller* (which hosts the `CustomContactsViewController` as it's root view controller).

Moreover, you can skip the Dispatch call, since we are in an @IBAction which already runs in the main thread:

```
@IBAction func didTouchAddFriend(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let navigation = UIStoryboard.init(name: "CustomContact", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController() as! UINavigationController
    let pickerUserVC = navigation.viewControllers.first as! CustomContactsViewController
    self.present(navigation, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Also, to dismiss the CustomContactsViewController you need to call dismiss on the viewController that presented the it, `navigationController?.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: I have almost 7 years of experience on iOS, and my title at my job is "iOS tech lead". But I still missed this one! LMAO. I should probably reconsider my career. Or I'm just trying to code with a cloudy head and trying hard to stay awake at 2:30AM.